# I want to call only child class constructor in multilevel inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, constructor-chaining

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("Constructor A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        System.out.println("Constructor B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public C() {
        System.out.println("Constructor C");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

When running the code then it calls all constructor but needs to call only child constructor.

output like only print

```
Constructor C
```

Comment: You can't do that. Period. You probably don't want to use inheritance for your use case

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: interviewer ask me

Comment: I need to know how to call only child class constructor

Comment: @SachinDoifode seems like a dumb interview question to me then. Maybe its possible using the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments and the other answer already said, **this is explicitly impossible**.

If a class (class `Foo`) extends another class (class `Bar`), then all constructors of `Foo` must directly or indirectly call one of the constructors of `Bar`. This is done either through explicit invocation or implicit invocation.

```
class Foo {

    // No constructor is specified, so a default, empty constructor is generated:
    // Foo() { }

}
```

```
class Bar extends Foo {

    Bar() {
        // Explicit call to a constructor of the super class is omitted, so a
        // default one (to Foo()) is generated:
        // super();
    }

}
```

In the [Java Language Specification § 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) it is written how new instances are created. For any class other than `Object` the super constructor is always executed.

> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.

So a `super` constructor is *always* called. If you want to print only "Constructor C", then you need to do any of the following:

- Change the constructor of `B` so it no longer prints "Constructor B" by either removing the `println` statement or removing the no-argument constructor alltogether.
- Add a second constructor within `B` which does not print anything and call it from `C`:

  ```
  B(boolean b) {

  }
  ```

  ```
  C() {
      super(true);
  }
  ```
- Make sure `C` does not extend `B` anymore:

  ```
  class C {
      public C() {
          System.out.println("Constructor C");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Lino You're right, fixed it. (And I swapped Foo and Bar.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. Java will call all constructors according the hierarchy.