# Java inheritance from class with same name

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been instructed (as part of an exercise) to create a class explicitly called 'Video' which must inherit from another class with the same name in a package I was given as a library.

I have tried simply writing:

```
public class Video extends Video
```

But it obviously fetches the local value of the video name and hence the compiler reports it as cyclic inheritance. 
So I tried prefixing the class with its package name:

```
public class Video extends pbt.util.Video
```

But then I get an error message saying the constructor isn't getting the right parameters (compiler thinking pbt.util.video is a call to the constructor of that class.)
So I then tried to declare the package:

```
package pbt.util.Video
```

But this (wierdly) gives me a "class, interface, or enum expected" error.
I cannot simply give my class another name (it MUST have the same name as specified by the exercise) but I cannot see how to make the inheritance work then.
Any thoughts are welcome :)

Comment: No problem to use fully qualified class name: `package test2;

public class Foo extends test.Foo`

Comment: Your second attempt of `public class Video extends pbt.util.Video` should work. Sounds like the `pbt.util.Video` doesn't have a default constructor, so your child class needs to have a constructor that matches the parent class.

Comment: so either provide a constructor with the same parameters, or explicitly call super(neededParameters);

Comment: *"...compiler thinking pbt.util.video is a call to the constructor of that class..."* No, it isn't. That version with the package name is correct. You need to code your `super` call in the constructor correctly, passing it the types of arguments it needs.

Comment: @Mike just tried it: it works fine if I define a constructor :) So is it normal that the compiler screams at me for not having a constructor that matches the super class? (quit new to inheritance)

Comment: @A.D *"So is it normal that the compiler screams at me for not having a constructor that matches the super class?"* Yes it is. [And no, you can't skip that part.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54629378/507738)

Comment: Ah ok, just read your link, that does make a whole lot more sense !